# Combining Resources of Multiple Servers

Tags: vps, hardware, cluster, resources

Can we combine resources of multiple servers into 1 and then create multiple vps's from the combined resources? For Example: Lets assume i have multiple servers with different HDD, RAM and Processor sizes and with any tool / mechanism,  i could combined their resources and create multiple VPS of different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called single system image clustering. While it is very interesting topic, but not very mature.

You can read about it more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image

Comment: I have studied that, and Yes its not yet been matured, and completely implemented properly, but it was a helpful topic. Thanks for the link.

Comment: this is by far the close to my requirement : http://www.scalemp.com/solutions/

Comment: it would be interesting to see it in practice :) so if you will use it - let us know how it goes!

Answer (score -1):

The number of resources  (mainly CPU and RAM) used by all VMs on a single server can not exceed the resources available on this machine, so if you have only 16GB of RAM on each server, you could never use more then those 16GB for a single VM.

However, virtualization environments can operate in a cluster that allows to share some resources like disk space and to move virtual machines to other hardware while they are running. This is what things like vSphere, KVM or OpenStack clusters do.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I know i cannot exceed from the available resources (CPU and RAM). But i can create multiple VM's from it, within my resources limit, right? 
Does OpenStack allow to merge physical resources in to one?

Comment: No, as I said: Resources can not be merged. Think about it: Even the fastest and most expensive interconnects between computers are way to slow to effectively share things like RAM.

Comment: Factually wrong.

Comment: @TomTom: In a useful sense, I don't think this is wrong. I am speaking about "regular VMs" in the ESXi or KVM sense. Of course you can interconnect machines but I am painfully aware of the buttloads of money we have to pour into the fastest possible IB interconnects and then still have my colleagues to optimize the hell of their programs to avoid using the shared memory wherever possible.

Comment: You do not. You may think you limit your answer to standard Hypervisors, but you do not. Which makes the answer wrong.